# fast way of creating href/src relative paths from current file in html tags

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I've started to use sublime text 2 and I was hoping for a fast way to create relative path references for the purpose of creating `hrefs` or `src` references?

E.g. say i had this file strucure:

```
myfolder
|-->css
|   `-->js
|       `-->something.js
`-->current.html
```

And i was editing a `<script src="[cursor_here]">` tag, I would like to use sublime's 'fuzzy' search function to quickly and accurately create the file path 'css/js/something.js by typing something like `cjs` and picking with my keyboard.

is this a base sublime functionality or is there a package for such a task or would I need to create this package myself?

Comment: `href` attribute on `<script>` won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`AutoFileName`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/AutoFileName) plugin from Package Control, it does exactly what you're describing. It can also do cool things like inserting dimensions for images, if you like. Make sure you read the README at the link above, and also go through the configuration options available in `Preferences -> Packages -> AutoFileName -> Settings-Default` (they'll need to be entered into `Preferences-User` if you want to change them).